# How do I get rid of specific parts of a string in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, path, scripting, applescript

Here is the string in question:

xxx:parentdir:childdir:file.fl

I want to get rid of all the characters starting with the first colon ":" until the end of the string so I'm left with just "xxx"

xxx varies in number of characters depending on my input.

It's an alias path and I just want the first bit of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characters in an AppleScript string have an index, or offset, relative to the start (1) or end (-1) of the string , and text can be specified using ranges, which have a staring and ending index.  For your example, you can search for the offset of the desired character or text, and use that as the ending position:

```
set testingText to (choose file) as text
set here to (offset of ":" in testingText) - 1 -- don't include the character
display dialog text 1 thru here of testingText
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to do it:

```
set foo to "xxx:parentdir:childdir:file.fl"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
set foo to first text item of foo as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

return foo
```

**Result:** "xxx"